# How do I use map or hashmap on spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Schema of my dataframe is as below;

```
    root
    |-- rowkey: string (nullable = true)
    |-- SALES: string (nullable = true)
    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
    |-- D_Parent_MID: string (nullable =         true)
    |-- D_ILK: string (nullable = true)
    |-- G_Parent_MID: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to use this data frame to further check for specific ID, is there "D_Parent_MID" present, if yes then use/store that value. if not then check "G_Parent_MID", if yes then use/store this value.

not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Can you provide an example (input and expected output) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you may use `withColumn` API, e.g.:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("ID", 
when(col("D_Parent_MID").isNotNull, col("D_Parent_MID"))
.when(col("G_Parent_MID").isNotNull, col("G_Parent_MID"))
.otherwise(col("ID"))
```

Hope it helps!